# Processing more than one type of field separator in single file

Tags: awk

Source file contains both comma delimited fields and pipe delimited fields.
It also contains duplicate header records both comma and pipe delimited.

** Souce File **

```
FOOID|BIZNO|BARBIZ_CODE
00033567|0035952|A,KEEP
00034145|0036865|A,KEEP
FOOID|BIZNO|BARBIZ_CODE
00030527|0032479|Z4,KEEP
00034984|0037987|Z5,KEEP
FOOID|BIZNO|BARBIZ_CODE
00021826|0022008|Z5,KEEP
00026763|0029293|Z5,KEEP
FOOID,BIZNO,BARBIZ_CODE
A0021826,Q022008,Z5,TRASH
B0021826,R022009,Z5,TRASH
C0021826,S022018,Z5,TRASH
FOOID,BIZNO,BARBIZ_CODE
```

I want to keep just one pipe delimited header and all the 
pipe delimited records.

Ignore the following:

1. All comma delimited fields records and headers
2. Duplicate pipe delimited headers.

**Assumptions**

1. First field in pipe delimiter header = FOOID
2. Pipe delimited fields may contain commas.

This awk script removes duplicate duplicate pipe  headers from my file.
How can I get it to ignore all CSV records?

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ FS="|"
      header_f1 = "FOOID" }
{
if (NR==1) { print $0 }
if (NR>1 && $1 != header_f1 && length > 1) { print $0 }
}
```

**Desired Results**

```
FOOID|BIZNO|BARBIZ_CODE
00033567|0035952|A,KEEP
00034145|0036865|A,KEEP
00030527|0032479|Z4,KEEP
00034984|0037987|Z5,KEEP
00021826|0022008|Z5,KEEP
00026763|0029293|Z5,KEEP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short **awk** approach:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1{ h=$1; print }NF>1 && NR>1 && $0!~"^"h' file
```

- `-F'|'` - treat `|` as field separator
- `NR==1{ h=$1; print }` - on encountering the 1st record assign the 1st header field `$1` to variable `h`(as header line indication)
- `NF>1` - print records which have at least 2 "`|`"-delimited fields
- `$0!~"^"h` - additional check to ensure that the record doesn't *relate* to header line

---

The output:

```
FOOID|BIZNO|BARBIZ_CODE
00033567|0035952|A,KEEP
00034145|0036865|A,KEEP
00030527|0032479|Z4,KEEP
00034984|0037987|Z5,KEEP
00021826|0022008|Z5,KEEP
00026763|0029293|Z5,KEEP
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your sample input, this appears to work:

```
$ awk 'NR == 1 { print } /,/ && /\|/ { print }' input
FOOID|BIZNO|BARBIZ_CODE
00033567|0035952|A,KEEP
00034145|0036865|A,KEEP
00030527|0032479|Z4,KEEP
00034984|0037987|Z5,KEEP
00021826|0022008|Z5,KEEP
00026763|0029293|Z5,KEEP
```

Always print the first (header) record; thenceforth print only records with both a comma and a pipe.